# SW for monitoring a bunch of REST services (installable on premises)

Tags: web-apps, monitoring, rest

Suppose you have a bunch of services exposed via REST APIs, what's the good SW to monitor those (mostly for uptime, not for performance)? With "good" defined as:

- easy and quick to install
- not overly complicated
- if possible, hackable (e.g. Python-based app would be nice)
- if possible, extensible via custom-written plugins

UPDATE: APIs would be a mix of existing SW REST APIs (say, like API exposed by ElasticSearch) and a number of APIs for services/microservices developed internally in the project.

Comment: Do you control the API? Can you add PING, or a test aparameter,  if it doesn't already exist?